# Linq query to object cannot pass Xunit test

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have strange problem. I have to pass the following Xunit test:

```
Fact]
     public void GetOrder_ValidId_ReturnsCompleteOrder()
     {
         var service = new DataService();
         var order = service.GetOrder(10248);
         Assert.Equal(3, order.OrderDetails.Count);
         Assert.Equal("Queso Cabrales", order.OrderDetails.First().Product.Name);
         Assert.Equal("Dairy Products", order.OrderDetails.First().Product.Category.Name);
     }
```

I am able to pass the orderdetails list to the test. However the "orderdetail" objects that i pass have a product object with null.

My classes are:

```
public class Order
{

    
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime Required { get; set; }

   [Required] public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    public string ShipName { get; set; }

    public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret =
            $"Id = {Id}, DateTime = {Date}, Required = {Required}, shipName= {ShipName}, Shipcity = {ShipCity}";

        return ret;
    }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("orders")]
    public int Orderid { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("products")]
    public int productid { get; set; }
    
    public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
    
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    

    [Required] public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public OrderDetail()
    {
        Product = Product;
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            $"OrderId = {Orderid}, Productid = {productid}";
    }

}


public class Product
{
    [ForeignKey("orderdetails")] public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    
    


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            $"Id = {Id}, Name = {Name}, UnitPrice = {UnitPrice}, QuantityPerUnit = {QuantityPerUnit}, UnitsInStock = {UnitsInStock}, CategoryId = {CategoryId}";
    }
}
```

I have the tried the following two solution:

```
public Order GetOrder(int id)
    {
        using var ctx = new NorthWindContext();

        var query =  ctx.Orders.AsQueryable().Where(o => o.Id == 10248).FirstOrDefault();
        

        ctx.SaveChanges();
        
        //var query2 = ctx.Orders.Include("orderdetails").Where()

        return query;


    }
```

and

```
 var query2 = ctx.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == 10248)
            .Select(a => new Order
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                OrderDetails = a.OrderDetails
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tried to reconfigure the mapping but didn't do it.
If i do the same query and use Console.Writeline in a foreach loop i can conclude that every orderdetail has a "product"...
I keep on the getting the error: "Object not set to an instance of an object" when passing to xUnit test.

Comment: `return ctx.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderDetails).ThenInclude(d => d.Product).FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == id);` See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Also cleanup your model - remove `ForeignKey` attributes (they are all invalid) as well as the code from `OrderDetail` constructor.

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for the reply.Whenever i am using include or theninclude i get a compiler error message that they are ambigious calls ... don't know how to fix...

Comment: Finally Thanks Ivan ! I removed one of the conflicting libraries and it worked and changes orderdetails to list instead of icollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivans response did the job.

First of all i removed `using System.Data.Entity;`

Then i changed the order class to the following:

```
public class Order 
{

    
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime Required { get; set; }

   [Required] public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    public string ShipName { get; set; }

    public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret =
            $"Id = {Id}, DateTime = {Date}, Required = {Required}, shipName= {ShipName}, Shipcity = {ShipCity}";

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then i used the following query just like Ivans:

```
 var query3 = ctx.Orders
            .Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.Product)
            .ThenInclude(d => d.Category)
            .AsSingleQuery()
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 10248);
```